# EFCore The Linq Expression Could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to create a compiled query that can be executed on the database side. The idea is to create a reusable function across my code. But EF Core is still saying this query cannot be translated to sql.

> Here is the reusable `expression`

```
public static class DisplayFilters
{
    public static Expression<Func<DisplayItem, bool>> isActiveItem = (x) => x.IsDeleted == false;
}
```

> Here is the EFCore entity call

```
using df = namespace.DisplayFilters;
...
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        IEnumerable<DisplayItem> xItem = (from a in _context.DisplayItem.AsQueryable()
                                          where df.isActiveItem.Compile()(a)
                                          select a);
        return Ok(xItem);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `Compile` if you want it to be passed to the database? `Compile` converts the `Expression` to local executable code (IL) on the client.

Comment: @NetMage I would see this issue then I posted, EFCore staff directed me to use expressions. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11335#issuecomment-374468813

Comment: @NetMage I may be way off in my understanding in how to use them.

Comment: BTW, is the `.AsQueryable()` really needed? Isn't `DisplayItem` already `IQueryable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can embed `Expression` type expressions in query comprehension syntax, but you can do it in lambda syntax:

```
IEnumerable<DisplayItem> xItem = _context.DisplayItem
                                 .Where(df.isActiveItem);
```

Comment: The `.AsQueryable()` was not needed. This is the solution though, it built the correct T-SQL.